# Some Javascript Doesn't Seem To Work On My Windows Laptop

Tags: browser

I think I got lucky to find this odd problem. I use weather.com to see weather, obviously. Along time ago I used IE and have been using Chrome now. I noticed that the dropdowns do not work on Chrome. The dropdowns also do not work on Firefox. The reason I noticed this problem is because they do work in IE. I've dealt with this problem for over a year and finally deciding to ask a question out of curiosity and the possibility that UI on other sites is also not working and I just never knew because I can't see it.

The dropdown works on my mac, and even on a VM on my Windows laptop. And countless other people I have asked, I can't find anyone else with this problem so it makes me think it is my browser/computer that is the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Browser order in video: IE11, Chrome, Firefox
Video: https://youtu.be/pN11rk5bc0o

Comment: Given the number of errors on the website I'm surprised it works at all https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fweather.com%2Fen-GB. Note some of the dropdown menus work for me on Firefox (not all)

Comment: Thanks for checking. Which dropdowns don't work? Interesting you're the first person I have found that has a similar issue. Maybe it is the site.

Comment: Forecast, Video and Weather are the only ones which work.

Comment: Actually I think I found a difference. It looks like you are redirected to en-GB. I checked the page source and the ones that don't work for you actually don't have dropdowns. I wonder if the content is different for en-GB. With that, I am back to thinking it is my browser/computer as the ones you mentioned are the only ones in the source that have dropdowns.

Comment: Are your browsers up to date? If yes they should work as for everyone else. I don't see any way that certain parts of javascript could fail the same way in two different browsers, as they have separate javascript engines. The only way this could happen is if some global program such as an ablock program run on windows is removing the javascript code, but then it would not work in IE either.